# How to find the third element value using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, selenium

All, i am currently trying to parse each element that has the format below using regex and c# to find any value in () below.. Example i would like to extract 2002_max_allow_date  .. note not all the names in here will be alpha numeric etc...

I initially have the pattern:   Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w\d\d\d.[A-Z])\w+");

However this only returns the name with the numeric etc

From reply i tried the following and trying to format this so that i do not get the syntax error as well as i don't want to change the regex query...

[image]

Can someone please assist me in finding the name located in the third position.. example this,'46032','46032','2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE'

```
<button class="longlist-cb longlist-cb-yes" id="cb46032" 
       onclick="$ll.CATG.toggleCb(this,'46032','46032','2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE')"
</button>
```

Comment: Do you need to get all values inside parentheses?

Comment: no i just need the 2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE or the names could be test_test or test123 etc just need to get that third element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
Regex rex = new Regex("'[^']+','[^']+','(?<ThirdElement>[^']+)'");
String data  = "'46032','46032','2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE'";
Match match = rex.Match(data);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["ThirdElement"]); // Output: 2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

SECOND EDIT:

I've written some code that provides all the elements inside the onclick as capture groups:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("onclick=\"\\$ll.CATG.toggleCb\\((.*),\\s?(.*),\\s?(.*),\\s?(.*)\\)");
string x = "<button class=\"longlist - cb longlist - cb - yes\" id=\"cb46032\" onclick=\"$ll.CATG.toggleCb(this, '46032', '46032', '2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE')\"></button>";
Match match = regex.Match(x);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("match.Value returns: " + match.Value);
    foreach (Group y in match.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the current capture group: " + y.Value);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.Write("No match");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

will print:
[image]

<del>EDIT: After trying with VS, this worked for me: `Regex regex = new Regex("onclick=\"\\$ll.CATG.toggleCb\\((.*),.*,.*,.*\\)");`</del>

<del>ORIGINAL ANSWER:
If you were to use `Regex regex = new Regex(@"onclick="\$ll.CATG.toggleCb\(.*,.*,(.*),.*\)");` on your provided text, that should return `'46032'`.</del>

<del>You could alter this regex by moving the capturing `(` and `)` to a different `.*` to capture, say, the fourth element, like this: `onclick="\$ll.CATG.toggleCb\((.*),.*,.*,.*\)` would capture `this`.</del>

Comment: This answer is targeted very specifically at the line you provided, so let us know if you want something more generic.

Comment: I just realized that this regex I provided will match the entire line, but the first capture group will be what you are looking for. Is that sufficient? If not I'll try to provide a better answer.

Comment: I basically only want the value 2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE or variation of those values that in third element after "this"  :this,'46032','46032','2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE'

Comment: See my edit to show you my VS error from the regex you provided.

Comment: ((.*),.*,.*,.*\) this seems to match what i am looking for

Comment: Yeah, that's the meat of the regex I tried to provide. I've edited my answer to include fixed syntax for VS.

Comment: Ok not exactly what i am looking for actually, so my results coming back is onclick="$ll.CATG.toggleCb(this,'45850','45850','1996_MAX_ALLOW_DATE')  But i just want to grab just  this value 1996_MAX_ALLOW_DATE'

Comment: \((.*),.*,.*,.*\)  gets me (this,'46032','46032','2002_MAX_ALLOW_DATE')  now what will be nice is to say omit this and get me value of the  third element separated by ,

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the attribute value of `onclick`, but to get the all HTML of the button which make question become complex.

And use `String.Split` can resolve your problem simply, but you choose to use RegExp.

`the_button_element.GetAttribute('onclick').Split(',')[3]`

Or use RegExp:

```
new Regex(@".*?,'(\w+)'\)$")
```

Comment: this is great advice as well.....thank you  .. this is good as well the_button_element.GetAttribute('onclick').Split(',')[3]